# What is downside of 'ReRender'ing really large amount of content(of which 90% is actually avoidable)?

Tags: apex, visualforce

If page has too many buttons/links with complicated rerendering logic; 
for simplicity what if we just 'Rerender' almost whole page?

What is downside of 'ReRender'ing really large amount of content(of which 90% is actually avoidable)? Is there risk of hitting any limits? Will it cause degradation in performance of page? is it really bad design? or just a stupid approach to even think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the exact mechanics of how rerender works aren't documented anywhere.

My understanding is that a full postback takes place, the page is completely reconstructed and delivered back to the calling page in an Ajax response, and JavaScript then plucks out the elements which need rerendering and discards the rest.  Thus I would say there isn't that much of an effect, as pretty much all of the work takes place before the rerendering, its just a matter of how much of the DOM is replaced.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Look like in that case, being picky about what to rerender isn't going to help much!

Answer (score 0):

It will surely  slow down the working of your page. Try breaking the page into chunks of forms and rerender these forms on your requirement. Or try making use of output panels.
On an additional note, if the avoidable content is querying any salesforce object then surely you will hit limits if the execution context dynamically raise the need of calls.